# Add HTML picture into Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm using Google Apps Script to create an automated email system, such that an email will be sent to the respondents when their form is submitted. I created another HTML file within this project, containing HTML formats for the body of my email. I used html format to craft a table, with my messages within and contains an image.

I tried running the project but it didn't work when my HTML file contains image, but it worked when I removed the image from my HTML file. Hence, I suspect it's the image that caused the HTML file and the project not to work. I'm unsure of how to include image in my HTML file, at the same time able to work.

```
function sendEmails(e) {

     var UserName = e.values[1];

     var UserEmail = e.values[3];

     var dateday = e.values[0];

     var pic = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("ccontent"); 

     var pin = e.values[2];

     var subject = "[LFR] Application Succeed!";

     var bodymessage = "Hi " + UserName + 

     "\n\n\n\nThank you for sending in your job application on " + dateday + " at" +
     "\n\nThe following is your Purchase Log Pin:\n" + pin +
     "\n\n\n\nBest Regards" +
     "\nLeoFresh Resorts OOA Team\n";

  MailApp.sendEmail(UserEmail, subject, "", 
                    { 
                      htmlBody: pic.evaluate().getContent() });
}
```

The following is my HTML file inside my Email Project, its file name is "ccontent". I'm trying this out with image inside a table and an example text, which would not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;    
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<table height='200' width='400'>

    <th><img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/2yydv2o.jpg" border="0" alt="error" width=500" height=100" align="middle"></th>


  <tr>
    <td>This is just to test whether it works with an image inside the table</td>

  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't get why you are using HTMLService Class to create the Mail Body. 
The procedure of creating a template and evaluating it "into" another part of your Apps Script is quite error-prone. Not saying that it wouldn't work but there is a much simpler way:

You can use HTML markup right in the mail-body using the **htmlBody param**: 
See [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailmessage) documentation. There is a good example with inline images.

However you will need to use inline style, as GMail (this is the service behind your MailApp Class) strips `<style>` tags from any mail displayed.

*Example* (I don't really know about replacing all `"` by `'` - maybe escpaing the `"`'s would've been better as HTML normally uses `"`):

```
<table height='200' width='400' style='border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;'>

    <th style='border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px;
text-align: left;'><img src='yourImageBlobSource' border='0' alt='error' width='500' height='100' align='middle'></th>


  <tr>
    <td style='border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px;
text-align: left;'>This is just to test whether it works with an image inside the table</td>

  </tr>
</table>
```